# How do I use Palatino Medium font?

Tags: fonts

[image]

Hello, I was able to successfully use the Palatino font. However, I find the bold a bit heavy and would like to use the Medium font. Is there any way to use the medium version without buying the actual font? Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}        
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} 
\usepackage{courier}
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}


Hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example which produces the output you show. Palatino is not distributed with TeX, so it isn't clear which font you're using or how you're using it. However, if you don't have a particular font, I don't see how you expect to be able to use it?

Comment: I just updated it with the sample.

Comment: Is `Palatino Medium` font available?

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a URW clone of Palatino.

The contents of directory `fonts/type1/urw/palatino/upl`:

```
uplb8a.pfb   uplb8a.pfm   uplbi8a.pfb  uplbi8a.pfm  uplr8a.pfb   uplr8a.pfm uplri8a.pfb  uplri8a.pfm
```

This shows the fonts available: `uplb*` are bold and `uplr*` are regular. That's what you have. There is no medium available.

You could try to find an alternative whose weights are more to your liking. For example, TeX-Gyre offers a Palatino clone which you might prefer. But there is nothing to be done for the font you are currently using because the alternative weights do not exist.